# Cant Connect to MongoDB server from Client

Tags: mongodb, windows-server, robo3t

I am trying to connect from my machine (client) to server, and it says I cant connect to server.
My machine is Windows 10 and Server machine is Windows Server 2016.

[image: Image 1]

And I tried to connect from cmd and it gives me this error.

[image: Image 2]

Help me with this problem please.

Comment: Images are useful in a post, but **make sure the post is still clear without them**. Instead of showing a screenshot of your data format, copy and paste or type the actual data into the post directly.
cf http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors

Answer (score 0):

You should check the following items on the server running MongoDB.

- Firewalls
- Whitelists

You should also verify basic network communication using something like `ping` from the client to the server.

Answer (score 0):

I will comment regarding Robomongo, seems like you are trying to connect to MongoDB 3.4 DB which only supported starting from the latest beta: [Robomongo 1.1 - Beta version with MongoDB 3.4 Support](https://github.com/Studio3T/robomongo/issues/1250#issuecomment-301036770)